# Installer for a bundle of Excel + VBA + exe files + CSV files

Tags: excel, installation, exe, vba

I have an Excel file + VBA code + csv files + exe files from another language. I can call exe files from VBA and all together they do the job for me. The performance and speed is important for my computational intensive applications, so I am satisfied with the performance of this bundle. Now there is the issue of making an easy to install package for the potential clients. I did my research about using dlls and building Add-Ins for Excel and at this time, I think this is not a productive path for me. I am looking to build a professional installation package for the following cases:

1- Installer puts an Excel workbook + CSV files and exe files in a right path for the client so she/he can immediately start working with the application.

2- A combination of an add-in which is written with VBA (hopefully) and an installer that  manages other VBA codes + CSV files and exe files to be put in the write path and places. I wouldn't like to compile the source code of computational exe files into dlls. I would like the add-in code that I would develop just to act as the installer or a manger of the above named code.

I appreciate if you could share your expertise and experience. My emphasis is in any case to use my computational exe file as they are, but it is still possible for me to re-compile the source codes to be consistent with the operating systems (Windows version and 32/64 bit machines).

Answer (score 0):

I use Setup Factory to do that.
You can find an example script to use as a starter [here](http://www.redcirclesoftware.com/setup-program-for-excel-addins/)

The only difficult bit is if you need to determine Excel bitness inside the installer without launching Excel. but maybe you can install both 32-bit and 64-bit exes and have the VBA determine which to call.